# How to get count particular value in a column - panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get count of value 10 in a particular column of dataframe.

```
 df:

    A    B

    a    10
    b    20
    c    10
```

I want simply count of 10 in column B , here it is 2.

Comment: Use `out = df['B'].eq(10).sum()`

Comment: in case I want to use > 10 then ?

Comment: then use `out = df['B'].gt(10).sum()`

Comment: [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html)
[`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html)
[`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.le.html)
[`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html)
[`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html)
[`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html)

Comment: `<` `>` `<=` `>=` `!=` `==`